# allocate memory for 2d array c

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I've been reading a lot of the posts about allocating memory, and I think that I understand the concept, but I have been told that I have to use an approach that looks something like this:

```
double ** malloc_array2d(size_t m, size_t n)
{
    double **A;
    size_t i;

    A = malloc(m * sizeof(double *));      
    if (A == NULL) 
        return NULL;
    A[0] = (double *) malloc(m * n * sizeof(double));   
    if (A[0] == NULL) 
    {
        free(A); 
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 1 ; i < m ; i++) 
        A[i] = A[0] + i  *n; 
    return A;
}
```

And then of course I will have to free the memory later - but I just don't quite understand this kind of approach and more specifically I can't really see what happens in the last line where the remaining pointers are set into the block of memory (have i been told. And I am not sure how I will insert elements in the matrix/array when I am done allocating.

Comment: You can always google..

Comment: And you can be consisten too, you cast the `malloc()` the second time only don't do it at all or do it even if it's ugly and  unnecessary but BE CONSISTENT.

Comment: That `for` loop is pretty small, try taking small concrete values (say `m=n=2`) and just write out what the function does, expanding the loop iterations. Draw boxes and arrows for the allocated blocks and pointers ... if you still can't see what's happening, explain which bits you _do_ understand.

Comment: This is *not* a 2D array but an weird emulation of it. This belongs in a museum, modern C can do better since C99. Just use `double (*arr)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[n][m]));` to allocate a 2D array in one go. You don't even need a special function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double ** malloc_array2d(size_t m, size_t n){

    double **A;
    size_t i;

    A = malloc(m*sizeof(double *));      
    if (A == NULL) return NULL;
    A[0]=(double *)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));   
    if ( A[0] == NULL) {free(A); return NULL;}
    for(i=1; i<m; i++) A[i]=A[0]+i*n; 

    return A;
}
```

Let's go Line by line:

```
A = malloc(m*sizeof(double *));
```

This line allocates space for m double pointers.

```
A[0] = (double *) malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
```

A[0] is now a block of memory for m*n doubles, which is all the doubles we need for the 2d array.

```
for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {A[i] = A[0] + i * n;}
```

because each A[i] is a block of n doubles, we want A[i] to start i*n doubles away from A[0].

Because all of this is in a solid block of memory, we can do some interesting things. For example, A[0][n] is the exact same double as A[1][0].

Furthermore, because everything is in one big block of memory, to access A[i][j] for any i < m, j < n, we just have to access the double at `A[0] + i*j + j`. This is much faster than going to A[i] which points to a double* B, and finding B[j].

Memory management is a difficult topic to understand and it takes some time. Hopefully this makes a bit more sense, and I hope I didn't confuse you even more :)

Comment: Thanks! This totally made sense :)

Answer (score 3):

With this form of allocation, you start by allocating an array of pointers to other arrays, like so:

```
T **a = malloc( sizeof *a * N ); // N is the number of rows
```

`sizeof *a` is equivalent to `sizeof (T *)`; each element of the array is going to be a pointer to `T`.  When we're done, we have something like the following in memory:

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
   |   | a[2]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[N-1]
   +---+
```

Now, for each of those elements, we allocate *another* chunk of memory to hold each element of type `T`:

```
a[i] = malloc( sizeof *a[i] * M ); // M is the number of columns
```

Each `a[i]` has type `T *`, so `sizeof *a[i]` is equivalent to `sizeof (T)`.

After that's done, we have something that looks like this in memory:

```
   +---+           +---------+---------+   +-----------+
a: |   | a[0] ---> | a[0][0] | a[0][1] |...| a[0][M-1] |
   +---+           +---------+---------+   +-----------+
   |   | a[1] ---> | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |...| a[1][M-1] |
   +---+           +---------+---------+   +-----------+
   |   | a[2] ---> | a[2][0] | a[2][1] |...| a[2][M-1] |
   +---+           +---------+---------+   +-----------+
    ... 
   +---+           +-----------+-----------+   +-------------+
   |   | a[N-1]--> | a[N-1][0] | a[N-1][1] |...| a[N-1][M-1] |
   +---+           +-----------+-----------+   +-------------+
```

So basically what you've done here is allocate `N` separate `M`-element arrays of `T`, and then you collect the pointers to those arrays in an `N`-element array of `T *`.

You can access each element as `a[i][j]`, like any normal 2D array; remember that the expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`; we offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from the address in `a` and then dereference the result.  So `a[i][j]` is evaluated as `*(*(a + i) + j )`.

So, several things to remember with this form of allocation:

1. The "rows" of the array are not going to be contiguous in memory; the object in memory following `a[i][M-1]` is (most likely) not going to be `a[i+1][0]`.
2. Since each "row" `a[i]` was allocated with a call to `malloc`, it must also be explicitly deallocated with a corresponding call to `free` *before* you deallocate `a` (always `free` in the reverse order that you `malloc`).
3. Even though we can treat `a` as a 2D-array, it does not have an array type, so you can't determine the size of the array using the `sizeof a` trick; you'll only get the size of the pointer type, not the total size of the array.  So you'll want to keep track of the array size yourself.

Answer (score -2):

You have to make each pointer of the pointer of poitners to point to valid `malloc()`ed data.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
    A[i] = (double *) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
```

You could also allocate it all at once, but then the notation `A[i][j]` will not work.

Comment: The code in the question does work. It allocates it all at once and then takes pointers into the allocated block.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the approach I see mostly when I google - and this one makes sense in my head - but I have just been told that this is the "naive" method and that a faster method is to allocate a big block m*n of memory and then set then set up the pointers into this block of memory - and my book says to do it like this :)